# Where can I get pre-trained model for YOLOv4 Tiny on COCO dataset?

Tags: opencv, object-detection, yolo

Guys I am trying to look for demo for object detection using **YOLOv4 Tiny** on every day objects. Therefore I am looking pre-trained model for **YOLOv4 Tiny** *pre-trained* on COCO dataset.After hours of searching I am only come across the similar tutorial on training on custom dataset from beginning using google Colab, I couldn't seem to find any pre-trained model for YOLOv4 Tiny model on COCO dataset.Can you give any reference where can I find a such a model?
Also I am trying to implement the model using OpenCV

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/master/cfg/yolov4-tiny.cfg and https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/releases/download/darknet_yolo_v4_pre/yolov4-tiny.weights first hit in googeling `tiny yolo v4 pretrained`